# Graphical view of layout in intellij Idea for android studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

By default graphical view is not opening in android studio.. and I'm unable to find toggle which says Design/Text in layout view..where to find?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open any layout file, the switch will be displayed as tabs at the bottom:

[image: Design/Text switch]

Note that you need to have **Android Designer** plug-in enabled:

[image: designer]

It's also important to open the files from the `src/main/res/layout` [directory](http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/121/p6m.png), not from the `build` directory.

If you open a file under `build`, latest Android Studio will display a warning on the top of the file:

[image: warning]

**Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited.**

Comment: CrazyCoder...thanks for reply!! though android designer is enabled...I'm unable to see the design and text options...

Comment: I have downloaded the IDE from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Comment: You open layout file from the `build` directory, you should not do it. Files must be open from the `src/main/res/layout` directory instead, everything under `build` should not be edited.

Comment: @KamilSeweryn in the current version it's done via Preview tool window options, Prefer XML Editor setting: http://i.imgur.com/hJN2t4P.png.