# Android Desinger plugin missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, android-studio

I got a problem that I don't have a design tab in a layout file to switch from the xml view to a graphical view. The problem is that the "design" tab in the layout is missing.

I've read an answer that said to switch between themes in the appearence settings but it did not work.

I've read here that you need to enable the Android Designer plugin:

[Graphical view of layout in intellij Idea for android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129778/graphical-view-of-layout-in-intellij-idea-for-android-studio)

But this plugin is missing from my list. It also does not appear in the "Install Jetbrain Plugin" and not in the "Browse repositories" button.

How do I get it? or maybe some other way to view the graphical view of a layout?

Comment: It says on the link you provided that it is bundled with the IDE. What version are you using? Have you tried downloading new AS from website? It should automatically pick up your settings after you run it.

Comment: My AS is already at 1.1.0

Comment: Don't mind that, reinstall it.